# Get the recently result in a 4shared consult

Tags: rest, sorting

I'm trying to sort a list of files that I'm getting in a 4shared REST response. But the documentation doesn't have any parameter.

My query is : `https://api.4shared.com/v0/files.json?oauth_consumer_key={application's consumer key}&category=3`

Anyone know the parameters to get the recently files in 4shared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 4shared documentation for the `GET /files` action says:

> Retrives list of public files ordered by date. Use filtering to make the request more specific.

So, your results is yet sorted by date. If you want only a subset of your files, you should use [pagination parameters](https://www.4shared.com/developer/docs/#pagination), e.g.:

```
https://api.4shared.com/v0/files.json?oauth_consumer_key={application's consumer key}&category=3&offset=20&limit=10"
```